# vb.net microsoft word bookmark

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

Is there any way i can create a bookmark on word document ?

I'm using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll` I know how to update text on existing bookmark in word document.

I wonder is there any way to create bookmark. It doesnt need ot be placed on document just to see it [image]

On this way i can change the bookmark text

```
  Private Sub document()

        Dim objWdDoc As Object
        Dim objWord As Object
        objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWdDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
        objWdDoc = objWord.Documents.Add("C:\Users\iml4203\Desktop\_korisno\Zahtjevikupca.docx")
        objWord.Visible = True

        With objWdDoc.Bookmarks
            .item("Bookmark1").Range.Text = "Test Bookmark"
            .item("Bookmark2").Range.Text = "Test Bookmark"
            .item("Bookmark2").Range.Text = "Test Bookmark"
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with `objWdDoc.Bookmarks.Add`?

Comment: Ken white that solved my problem i didnt know that command exist at all . Post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Bookmark.Add` to create a new bookmark. This should get you started (untested!)...

```
 With objwDoc.Bookmarks.Add
     ' Set the individual properties of the bookmark here
 End With
```